# I am unable to give path to save image inside resource folder using springboot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am newbie to springboot and want to save image inside the resource folder so that i doesn't need to save inside the database.

```
  @Component
  public class FileUploadServiceImpl {

public final String
UPLOAD_DIR = new ClassPathResource("resources/image").getFile().getAbsolutePath();
public FileUploadServiceImpl() throws IOException {
}
public boolean uploadFile(MultipartFile multipartFile) throws IOException {
    boolean f = false;
    String fileName = StringUtils.cleanPath(multipartFile.getOriginalFilename());
    Files.copy(multipartFile.getInputStream(), Paths.get(UPLOAD_DIR + "//" +                                                 multipartFile.getOriginalFilename()),
            StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    f = true;
    return f;
}
}
```

Error:

```
 class path resource [resources/image] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
```

Comment: Spring Boot applications are usually launched via JARs or WARs, and it's definitely not a good idea to upload images inside these archives and store them on a classpath. It's better to create folder on a file system and store uploaded images there.

Comment: can you share some more idea on how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check your folders directory...
I am sharing my folders directory and ClassPathResource
[Click here for pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xdijt.png)

Also, check my  ClassPathResource

```
    public final String UPLOAD_DIR = new ClassPathResource("/static/images/").getFile().getAbsolutePath();
```